# How do I push results from Puppeteer page.evaluate to a csv file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, puppeteer

How can I push the data of the page.evaluate into a csv file for me to analyse?

Thank you in advance.

I am doing some webscraping that runs a loop for the number of pages and pulling the reviews option description.

However, though I am able to console.log the results but I cannot seem to join them together or get them in a csv file format. Would anyone be able to help on this?

Thanks just started to learn coding and have many many more things to learn.....

```
puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const CREDS = require('./creds');


(async function main() {
    try{
        const URL = 'https://www.qoo10.sg/gmkt.inc/Login/Login.aspx'; 

        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
        const page = await browser.newPage();


        await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36')

        await page.goto(URL ,{waitUntil:'networkidle0'});


        const USERNAME_SELECTOR = '#login_id';
        const PASSWORD_SELECTOR = '#passwd';
        const BUTTON_SELECTOR = '#dv_member_login > fieldset > a';

        await page.click(USERNAME_SELECTOR);
        await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.username);

        await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
        await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.password);

        await page.click(BUTTON_SELECTOR);

        await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil:'networkidle0'});

        const itemUrl = 'https://www.qoo10.sg/item/FANCO-FANCO-CEILING-FAN-FFM2000-FFM3000-FFM4000-FFM6000-LIGHT-KITS/496619203?banner_no=1305330';

        await page.goto(itemUrl, {waitUntil:'networkidle0'});

        const photoreviewsnumber = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#divPremiumList > div.rv_tit.photo > h2 > span').innerText);
        const photoreviewspage = Math.ceil(photoreviewsnumber/5);

            for (let i = 0; i < photoreviewspage; i++) {
            const button = await page.$('#photo_review_paging > a.next');
            button.click();



            const options = await page.evaluate(() => 
                Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('p.dtl')).map(partner => partner.innerText)
            );

            await page.waitFor(500);

            console.log(result);
            console.log(i);
        }

        await browser.close();

    } catch(e) {
        console.log('our error', e);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what issue you have, but maybe these changes can help?

```js
    const allOptions = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < photoreviewspage; i++) {
      const button = await page.$('#photo_review_paging > a.next');
      await button.click();
      await page.waitFor(500);

      const options = await page.evaluate(() =>
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('p.dtl')).map(partner => partner.innerText)
      );

      console.log(options);
      allOptions.push(options);
      console.log(i);
    }
    console.log(allOptions.join('\n'));
```

Otherwise, please add more details, what data can you get versus what data should you get.

Comment: I want to push all the data into a csv type format like data, data1, data2.... So I can open it in excel to do a pivot table

Comment: So you can get all the needed data from the puppeteer and you just need to convert it to CSV and write to the file?

Comment: Yes you are right. I would like to push all the data to a csv. Do I use a FS or something?

Comment: This is the data I get after change /n to () only which I think returns a default , as the join

Comment: Model:FFM2000 | Color:GM(+S$24) | Remote Controller:none | Fan Lights:402|4 (FFM2000 Only)(+S$60) | Light Bulb Colour:Day light (White),Model:FFM6000 | Color:WH(+S$44) | Remote
Controller:none | Fan Lights:none | Light Bulb Colour:none,Model:FFM3000 | Color:WH | Remote Controller:Yes(+S$50) | Fan Lights:007|2XE27 (FFM3000|4000|6000 Only)(+S$50) | Light Bulb Colour:Warm White (Orange),Model:FFM2000 | Color:MS(+S$24) | Remote Controller:none | Fan Lights:none | Light Bulb Colour:none,  ..........

Comment: If you write just local utility and need not any asynchrony, you can use [fs.writeFileSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) to save csv in the file. If you need a safe way to convert to CSV before writing, you can try any [appropriate csv module from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=csv&ranking=popularity).

Comment: for (let i = 0; i < photoreviewspage; i++) {
            const button = await page.$('#photo_review_paging > a.next');
            button.click();
            
            const options = await page.evaluate(() =>
                Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('p.dtl')).map(partner => partner.innerText)
          );
        await page.waitFor(500);
        await allOptions.push(options);
        }

        fs.writeFileSync('result.csv' ,allOptions.join('\n'));

Comment: Got it and I used this but weirdly everypage which consists of 5 options is in 1 column when I open it up in excel so I have like 30 columns. How can I put it all in 1 line instead of each page going into a column. not sure if you understand what I meant lolz as I cannot attach a file.

Comment: Can you provide these examples at the end of your question: 1. data from one page. 2. What you really get overall after the script ends. 3. What you need to obtain.

Comment: If you take a look at this excel you wil see the results all split into different columns. I want them all in the same column

Comment: Sorry, I am not so aware in CSV and Excel. I've added these tags to your question, let's hope somebody else will help.